# reading a file and printing the average from strings and integers

Tags: java, file, io, split

I have a text file containing on each line a name and a sequence of integers, for instance

```
Jules 50 60 40
Ali 45 70 70 90
Emma 45 54
```

I have this for my code but it does not print out the average also I'm not sure on how to read sequence of integers

```
   public void AverageMarks(String fName, String pname) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    try{ 
         br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fName));
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("Could not find file");
    }

    try{    
        double average = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        String line;

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
          String[] lines = line.split(" ");

           if(pname.equals(lines[0])){
                for(int i =0; i<lines.length; i++){
              sum+= Double.parseDouble(lines[i+1]);
            } 
             average = sum / lines.length;
            System.out.println(average);
            System.exit(0);
          }
          else{
              System.out.println(pname + " No such name");
              System.exit(0);
            }
        }

    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("An error has occured");
    }
    finally{
        System.exit(0);
    }
  }
```

For example the average is a double...

- `AverageMarks("myfile.txt","Jules")` should print `50.0`
- `AverageMarks("myfile.txt","Ali")` should print `68.75`
- `AverageMarks("myfile.txt","Neil")` should print `Neil No such name`

Comment: what is the output ?

Comment: The first I see: If the name does not match, it still calculates the average (0 divided by line-length = 0) and prints it end exits. So if the name is not in first line you always get the output 0, right?

Comment: The output should be the average of the integer values so if the name matches the name passed in the argument it would return average

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is, you should not have `else` block in you `while` loop. `else` block statements should be out of look to make sure that you have processed all the lines in the file and no such name exists. Also there was problem with `for` loop index. It should start from `1` not from `0`. Try this:

```
public void AverageMarks(String fName, String pname) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    try{ 
         br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fName));
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("Could not find file");
    }

    try{    
        double average = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        String line;

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
          String[] lines = line.split(" ");

          if(pname.equals(lines[0])){
            if(lines.length > 1) { // check to calculate average only when there are numbers as well in the line
              for(int i = 1; i<lines.length; i++){ // loop index shold start from 1 as element at index 0 is name
                sum+= Double.parseDouble(lines[i]);
              }

              average = sum / (lines.length - 1);
            }
            System.out.println(average);
            System.exit(0);
          }
        }

        // moved these lines from inside loop, to make sure all the names in the files have been checked
        System.out.println(pname + " No such name");
        System.exit(0);

    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("An error has occured");
    }
    finally{
        System.exit(0);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much the comments helped alot I appreciate it :)

Comment: Before posting a question please try to debug your code. Believe me its not that hard.